# Puppet agent logging on Ubuntu?

Tags: puppet

I'm looking for the logs on a puppet agent on Ubuntu. According to the [Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/services_agent_unix.html#logging-for-puppet-agent-on-nix-systems) it should be in `/var/log/messages`.

> Logging for Puppet agent on *nix systems When running as a service,
>   Puppet agent logs messages to syslog. Your syslog configuration
>   dictates where these messages are saved, but the default location is
>   /var/log/messages on Linux, /var/log/system.log on Mac OS X, and
>   /var/adm/messages on Solaris.

I've set `log_level` to `debug`. I don't seem to have a `/var/log/messages` file. I do have folders `/var/log/puppetlabs/puppet` and `/var/log/puppetlabs/pxp-agent` but both of these folders are empty.

<s>*Edit: [Reading](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/configuration.html#loglevel) that the default logdir is `/var/log/puppetlabs/puppet`. But I never have log files when I look.*</s> Striking out because I think this applies to puppet server not the agent.

Comment: I thought `/var/log/messages` is a standard file for logging system messages on all Linux. It really does not exist?

Comment: @MattSchuchard No I have an ARM device and a Docker version and neither have a `/var/log/messages` file. I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 on both.

Comment: @MattSchuchard maybe it's an issue with logging in general. I found a general logging file at `/var/log/syslog` on the ARM version. It contains logs from several programs including puppet.

Comment: Ok; I triple-checked the documentation and the claim is that file is universal for logging on Linux, which is what I thought. If you found counter-examples, then that cannot be denied.

Comment: @MattSchuchard apparently Ubuntu stopped using `/var/log/messages` as far back as Ubuntu 11, in 2011 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84634/16792

Comment: Well, it seems like you found your answer, right? I am pretty sure this is the full extent of logging on a local system and if you want anything better you are looking at a reporter that ties in with PuppetDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Ubuntu stopped using `/var/log/messages` as far back as Ubuntu 11, in 2011. It now uses `/var/log/syslog`.

I foud [this unix exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84633/where-is-var-log-messages/84634#84634) with more information:

> Ubuntu no longer uses the /var/log/messages file by default. The same
>   information is available in the file /var/log/syslog. You can
>   re-enable logging to /var/log/messages if you would like.
>
> Ubuntu no longer uses the `/var/log/messages` file by default. The
>   same information is available in the file `/var/log/syslog`. You can
>   [re-enable logging to
>   `/var/log/messages`](http://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/tag/ubuntu-10-04-varlogmessages/)
>   if you would like.
>
> Syslog is a standard logging facility. It collects messages from
>   various programs, including the kernel. It is usually configured to
>   store these messages by default. How it stores these messages is
>   generally distribution-dependant. `/var/log/messages` is generally
>   used to store non-critical messages while `/var/log/syslog` stores
>   everything, including critical and non-critical messages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Ubuntu 16.04 you can run the following to see the Puppet agent logs:

```
journalctl -u puppet.service
```

Hope this helps.